# Concrete categories and the concept of to be free

Tags: category-theory

Let $F$ be free on the set $S$, let $F′$ be free on the set $S′$, and
assume that $|S| = |S′|$. Prove that there is an isomorphism
$g : F → F′$.

By definition we have: $f:  S → U(G)$, $i:  S → U(F)$ s.t. $f=U(f*) \circ i $ for some $f*:F \to G$. Same for $f', f*', F', G'$. How do you define the isomorphism of $F$ and $F'$ from this diagrams?

thanks!

Comment: Use the fact that taking free objects is a functor, so sends isomorphisms to isomorphisms.

Comment: Step 1: Make sure you have the correct idea of what free means (at the moment you are at least missing that something is unique, and from what you wrote it is unclear whether you understand that $i$ is fixed and that you need to quantify over every "$f$"). Step 2: Let $\phi :S\to S'$ be an bijection, use the universal property of $i$ and the composite $i'\phi $ to obtain a morphism $g: F\to F'$. Step 3: Use the universal property of $i'$ and the composite $i\phi^{-1}$ to obtain a morphism $g' : F \to F'$. Step 4: Use the universal properties of $i$ and $i'$ to show that $g'g=id$ and $gg'=id$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a concrete category with forgetful functor $U : \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Set}$.
Suppose that $S, S^\prime$ are sets with $|S|=|S^\prime|$ and $F, F^\prime$ are objects of $\mathcal{C}$ with $F$ free on $S$ and $F^\prime$ free on $S^\prime$. Let $i : S \to U(F)$ and $i^\prime : S^\prime \to U(F^\prime)$ be the canonical injections.

Recall the universal property of $F$: for every object $A$ of $\mathcal{C}$ and every function $f : S \to U(A)$, there exists a unique morphism $g : F \to A$ in $\mathcal{C}$ satisfying $f = U(g) \circ i$. That is, for every object $A$ of $\mathcal{C}$, there is an isomorphism
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(F, A)
\overset{\sim}{\to} \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Set}}(S, U(A)),
$$
given by $g \mapsto U(g) \circ i$.

$F^\prime$ satisfies a similar universal property.

Since $|S|=|S^\prime|$, there is an isomorphism (in $\mathbf{Set}$) $h : S \to S^\prime$. Let $f = i^\prime \circ h : S \to U(F^\prime)$. By the universal property of $F$, there exists a unique morphism $g : F \to F^\prime$ such that $f = U(g) \circ i$.
Similarly, let $f^\prime = i \circ h^{-1} : S^\prime \to F$. By the universal property of $F^\prime$, there exists a unique morphism $g^\prime : F^\prime \to F$ such that $f^\prime = U(g^\prime) \circ i^\prime$. Then $g \circ g^\prime : F \to F$ satisfies
$$
\begin{aligned}
U(g^\prime \circ g) \circ i
&= U(g^\prime) \circ U(g) \circ i \\
&= U(g^\prime) \circ f \\
&= U(g^\prime) \circ i^\prime \circ h \\
&= f^\prime \circ h \\
&= i \circ h \circ h^{-1} \\
&= i.
\end{aligned}
$$
Since $U(\operatorname{id}_F) \circ i = i$, the universal property of $F$ implies that $g^\prime \circ g = \operatorname{id}_F$. An analogous argument shows that $g \circ g^\prime = \operatorname{id}_{F^\prime}$. Therefore $g^\prime = g^{-1}$, and hence $F$ and $F^\prime$ are isomorphic.